# PHP Preg_Replace, "starts with" wont work

Tags: php, preg-replace, startswith

Could someone explaine me, why my code gives me nothing back?

```
<?php
    $text = '<article about="about_text" typeof="sioc:Item foaf:Document" class="node node-bildergalerie node-published node-not-promoted node-not-sticky author-lalala odd clearfix" id="node-bildergalerie-6835">';
    $search_for = '(author\-.*?)\s';
    $replace = '';
    print preg_replace($search_for, $replace, $text);
?>
```

Comment: `$search_for = '/(author\-.*?)\s/';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php):

```
$search_for = '~(author\-\w+)\s~';
```

Also changed the [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `.*?` to `\w+` where `\w` is a [shorthand](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) to word characters so one or more `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`

Comment: Works, thank you, is there a difference between '~' and '/' ?

Comment: It's up to you, best to pick something not very common :)

Comment: @Leri Yes, prefer `~` because I usually don't need that inside my patterns. `/` for me is a rather bad one, because much more cases where it could occur inside delimiters and would have to escape it then.

Comment: @Jonny5 Honestly, from my practice the only case when `/` delimiter creates readability problem is with paths. However, all I wanted to say is that you should go with whatever you find readable and there's no golden rule which delimiter to use. ;)

Comment: @Leri I work much with urls, so I don't like `/` as delimiter because there's a lot of escaping necessary. E.g. `'~(?<=://)[^/?\s]+(?=[?/\s])~'` vs `'/(?<=:\/\/)[^\/?\s]+(?=[?\/\s])/'`. Imho it depends on what you're doing. I prefer `~` as delimiter, use single-quotes for the pattern and totally understand that you might have other needs/preferences.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a well formed regular expression. You need to add delimiters:

```
<?php
    $text = '<article about="about_text" typeof="sioc:Item foaf:Document" class="node node-bildergalerie node-published node-not-promoted node-not-sticky author-lalala odd clearfix" id="node-bildergalerie-6835">';
    $search_for = '/(author\-.*?)\s/';
    $replace = '';
    print preg_replace($search_for, $replace, $text);
?>
```

Check it out in this fiddle: http://codepad.org/WSNCktk0